# Unsure what the "c" in the parameter list is

Tags: java, uml

I am writing a program from a UML diagram.

How would I represent this method?

I know the method is calculateCharges, but I am unsure how to represent the parameters in the braces. All I am certain of is that double is the type I would like to return and that CustomerType is the enum I declared in my customer class.

Any help?

```
+calculateCharge(c:Customer.CustomerType):double
```

Comment: It's a public method (`+`), named `calculateCharge` which takes a variable, `c`, of type `Customer.CustomerType` and returns a `double`.

Comment: public Customer.CustomerType calculateCharge(double c)
        {
            return ( );
        }

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 public double calculateCharge(Customer.CustomerType c) {
      return c;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but if it is a return type of double, how can I use the variable c since that is just an integer?

Comment: @AaronGabriel later when you you call the method you pass it value like this `calculateCharge(3)`